# Changing windows 7 version?

Tags: windows-7, windows, upgrade

I just made a very stupid mistake.

I re-installed windows about 5 days ago, just finished reinstalling the old programs, movies the files where they need to go, etc.  When I realize I didn't activate windows.  It turns out I have the wrong version of windows installed.  Basic instead of Premium.  I have the Premium key (which costs more then basic) so it goes beyond me why I can't use it for a basic version, but I can't.

Is there anyway to upgrade my windows box to premium (so I can use my key), or will I need a fresh install?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure it works in this situation, but you can try an "Anytime Upgrade". This is not something that you will start, and then not be able to finish. It should be clear early on if you follow the directions below (or the video), whether it will work or not.

If it works, it will just go out to the Internet, download some components, and then do a "light" upgrade...just the changes, not a whole upgrade, like back in the pre-XP days. Takes about 15 minutes, give or take.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/videos/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-7-by-using-windows-anytime-upgrade

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMCoJW-b5zo

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for saving me all the extra work!

Comment: Glad I could help.